# Where do # of epochs and batch size belong in the hyperparameter tuning process?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, hyperparameters

I'm fairly new to machine learning, and working on optimizing hyperparameters for my model. I'm doing this via a randomized search. My question is: **should I be searching over # of epochs and batch size along with my other hyperparameters (e.g. loss function, number of layers, etc.)? If not, should I fix a these values first, find the other parameters, then return to tune these?**

My concern is a) that searching over many epochs will be extremely time-consuming, so leaving it at one low value for the initial scan would be useful and b) that these parameters, esp. # of epochs, will disproportionately affect the results when the model is behaving well, and won't really give me much information about the rest of my architecture, as there should be a regime where more epochs, up to a point, are better. I know this isn't totally accurate, i.e. # of epochs is a real hyperparameter and too many can lead to overfitting issues, for example. Currently, my model is not clearly improving with # of epochs, though it was suggested by someone working on a similar problem within my area of research that this may be mitigated by implementing batch normalization, which is another parameter I am testing. Finally, I am worried that batch size will be quite affected by the fact that I am scaling my data down to 60% to allow my code to run reasonably (and I think the final model will be trained on vastly more data than the simulated data currently available to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your intuition on epochs. It is common to keep this value as low as possible in order to complete more training "experiments" in the same number of working hours. I don't have a great reference here, but I would welcome one in the comments.

For almost everything else, there is a paper by Leslie N. Smith that I can't recommend enough, [A disciplined approach to neural network hyper-parameters: Part 1 -- learning rate, batch size, momentum, and weight decay](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09820).

As you can see, batch size is included but epochs are not. You will also notice that the model architecture is not included (number of layers, layer size, etc). [Neural Architecture Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_architecture_search) is a huge research field in its own right, separate from hyper-parameter tuning.

---

As for the loss function, I can't think of any reason to "tune" that except in the context of an Auxiliary Loss for training only, which I suspect is not what you are talking about.

The loss function that will be applied to your validation or test set is part of the problem statement. That, along with the data, defines the problem you are solving. You don't changing it by tuning, you change it by convincing a product manager that your alternative is better for the business need.

Comment: Thanks for your robust answer, I will look into the papers! What you have noted about the loss function is interesting. For the purposes of my project, the score we have generally been trying to optimize is roc-auc, as this is a binary classification with lots of background. Would there be a natural way to translate this into a loss function? So far, my team has been using a custom "focal loss" function instead during training.

Comment: I should probably add a little bit about my set up, although I was trying to be initially vague as I was more interested in the general theory.

I'm using a Keras Sequential MLP built on top of TensorFlow to perform a binary classification. I'm training on many data points, but the data is fairly simple, currently with only 10 values per datapoint. My data also has a very large signal to background ratio, for some of my datasets this ratio is more that 300:1. Currently, I've been exploring the effects of the architecture, activations, loss, optimizer, dropout, and batch normalization.

Comment: The ROC-AUC topic sounds like a very good one for another question :) I admit I don't know the answer, or even if it has already been asked here. But I'd be willing to read a bit about it and see if I can help. The first thing that comest to mind is LambdaMART and the related learn to rank algorithms, which use some clever insights to optimize over NDCG (or other ranking metrics) which are also non-differentiable.